# how to print only lines which contain a substring

Tags: python, list

i have a file with strings:

```
REALSTEP 12342 {2012-7-20   15:10:39};[{416 369 338};{423 432 349};{383 380 357};{399 401 242};{0 454 285};{457 433 115};{419 455 314};{495 534 498};][{428 377 336};{433 456 345};{386 380 363};{384 411 
REALSTEP 7191 {2012-7-20    15:10:41};[{416 370 361};{406 417 376};{377 368 359};{431 387 251};{0 461 366};{438 409 134};{429 411 349};{424 505 364};][{423 372 353};{420 433 374};{379 365 356};{431 387 2
REALSTEP 12123 {2012-7-20   15:10:42};[{375 382 329};{386 402 347};{374 378 357};{382 384 259};{0 397 357};{442 424 188};{398 384 356};{392 420 355};][{404 405 359};{420 432 372};{405 408 383};{413 407 
REALSTEP 27237 {2012-7-20   15:10:44};[{431 375 329};{416 453 334};{387 382 349};{397 403 248};{0 451 300};{453 422 131};{433 401 317};{434 505 326};][{443 384 328};{427 467 336};{391 386 344};{394 413 
FAKE 32290 {2012-7-20   15:10:48};[{424 399 364};{408 446 366};{397 394 389};{415 409 261};{0 430 374};{445 428 162};{432 416 375};{431 473 380};][{424 398 376};{412 436 372};{401 400 390};{417 409 261}
FAKE 32296 {2012-7-20   15:10:53};[{409 326 394};{445 425 353};{401 402 357};{390 424 250};{0 420 353};{447 423 143};{404 436 351};{421 527 420};][{410 332 400};{450 429 356};{402 403 356};{391 425 250}
FAKE 32296 {2012-7-20   15:10:59};[{381 312 387};{413 405 328};{320 387 376};{388 387 262};{0 402 326};{417 418 177};{407 409 335};{443 502 413};][{412 336 417};{446 437 353};{343 417 403};{417 418 258}
FAKE 32295 {2012-7-20   15:11:4};[{377 314 392};{416 403 329};{322 388 375};{385 391 261};{0 403 329};{425 420 168};{414 393 330};{458 502 397};][{408 338 421};{449 435 355};{345 418 403};{413 420 257};
FAKE 32295 {2012-7-20   15:11:9};[{371 318 411};{422 385 333};{342 379 352};{394 395 258};{0 440 338};{418 414 158};{420 445 346};{442 516 439};][{401 342 441};{456 415 358};{367 407 377};{420 420 255};
FAKE 32296 {2012-7-20   15:11:15};[{373 319 412};{423 386 333};{344 384 358};{402 402 257};{0 447 342};{423 416 151};{422 450 348};{447 520 442};][{403 342 442};{456 416 358};{366 409 379};{422 421 255}
REALSTEP 7191 {2012-7-20    15:10:41};[{416 370 361};{406 417 376};{377 368 359};{431 387 251};{0 461 366};{438 409 134};{429 411 349};{424 505 364};][{423 372 353};{420 433 374};{379 365 356};{431 387 2
REALSTEP 12123 {2012-7-20   15:10:42};[{375 382 329};{386 402 347};{374 378 357};{382 384 259};{0 397 357};{442 424 188};{398 384 356};{392 420 355};][{404 405 359};{420 432 372};{405 408 383};{413 407 
REALSTEP 27237 {2012-7-20   15:10:44};[{431 375 329};{416 453 334};{387 382 349};{397 403 248};{0 451 300};{453 422 131};{433 401 317};{434 505 326};][{443 384 328};{427 467 336};{391 386 344};{394 413
```

I read the file with readlines() and want to then loop over the lines and print only when there is a consecutive block of lines larger than 3, containing the string "REALSTEP". So in the example the expected result is:

```
REALSTEP 12342 {2012-7-20   15:10:39};[{416 369 338};{423 432 349};{383 380 357};{399 401 242};{0 454 285};{457 433 115};{419 455 314};{495 534 498};][{428 377 336};{433 456 345};{386 380 363};{384 411 
REALSTEP 7191 {2012-7-20    15:10:41};[{416 370 361};{406 417 376};{377 368 359};{431 387 251};{0 461 366};{438 409 134};{429 411 349};{424 505 364};][{423 372 353};{420 433 374};{379 365 356};{431 387 2
REALSTEP 12123 {2012-7-20   15:10:42};[{375 382 329};{386 402 347};{374 378 357};{382 384 259};{0 397 357};{442 424 188};{398 384 356};{392 420 355};][{404 405 359};{420 432 372};{405 408 383};{413 407 
REALSTEP 27237 {2012-7-20   15:10:44};[{431 375 329};{416 453 334};{387 382 349};{397 403 248};{0 451 300};{453 422 131};{433 401 317};{434 505 326};][{443 384 328};{427 467 336};{391 386 344};{394 413
```

I tried this:

```
lines = f.readlines()
idx = -1
#loop trough all lines in the file
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if idx > i:
        continue
    else:
        if "REALSTEP" in line:
            steps = lines[i:i+3]
          #check for blokc of realsteps
            if is_block(steps, "REALSTEP") == 3:
                #prints the block up to the first next "FAKE STEP"
                lst = get_block(lines[i:-1])
                for l in lst:
                    print l[:200]
                idx =  i + len(lst)
                print "next block============"
```

where the function is_block is this:

```
def is_block(lines, check):
    #print len(lines)
    bool = 1
    for l in lines:
        if check in l:
            bool = 1
        else:
            bool = 0
        bool = bool + bool
    return bool
```

and the function get_block:

```
def get_block(lines):
    lst = []
    for l in lines:
        if "REALSTEP" in l:
            #print l[:200]
            lst.append(l)
        else:
            break
    return lst
```

While this works, it prints all lines containing the string "REALSTEPS". The print len(lines) in is_block(lines) is always 10 when the function is called so that is not it.

I am confused, please help me out here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple solution containing the logic you need:

```
to_print = []
count = 0
started = False
for line in f.readlines():
    if "REALSTEP" in line:
        if not started: 
            started = True
        to_print.append(line)
        count += 1
    else:
        if count > 3: print('\n'.join(to_print))
        started = False
        count = 0
        to_print = []
```

It counts any line that has the string "REALSTEP" in it as valid. Produces the desired output.

Comment: I generally don't think that handing over an answer on a silver platter is the best way to do it... No one learns. But meh.

Comment: @Colin Dunklau How would you suggest improving that line?

Comment: @voithos I guess you're right but the given solution is very clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
...
    if "REALSTEP" in line:
        steps = lines[i:i+3]
        for s in steps:
            print s[:200]  # <- right here
...
```

Whenever you find `"REALSTEP"` in a line, you retrieve the following three lines and print them right away. That's probably not what you wanted.

Comment: indeed, thats not what i wanted. I removed it but the problem persists. It was there only for testing. I'll hav another look tommorow